# WPF-win32 Interoperation

Tags: wpf, winapi, wpf-controls

I have a win32 project which is very complex and i successfully referenced that in my wpf.
Now my Question i have created a dialogue in wpf which select a file,but the function which process this file written in win32 part of my project.  is it possible to access a particular function written in win32 part in wpf?

Comment: i solved this problem by accessing the value in WPF and overloaded win32 function in wpf.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes you can. It does't have limitations in using classes (cuz they are still written in C#, right?)
So, go ahead. Everything should work. If you have troubles, let us know.

p.s.The one who set downvote, explain where I was wrong. I'd like to know what did mean.

Comment: My problem from wpf how will i access my win32 function?

Comment: could you describe a little bit more about your case? Or may be any sample?

Comment: ok, my win32 application was very old and i wanted it to work inside the wpf.so using    HwndHost i connected both. now i created a wpf dialogue which select a file. now i wanted to send this file to my win32 function, is there any way to do that??

Comment: sorry user1353565, may be I've misunderstood you. Is your main (host) project WinForm project? I've just create a sample WinForm project and added wpf Window. From WinForm form code behind called                 new MainWindow().ShowDialog(); and it worked just fine. Your wpf dialogue still have code behind, right, so you can work with it as you usually do

Comment: just opposite my parent window is WPF and win32 referenced as a dll in it.

Comment: anyway it shouldn't cauze any problem. What exactly doesn't work? I don't see any problems here. Any exceptions or compile errors?

Comment: the problem was i was not able to access some function written in the win32 project. now i made a long route to access but serve the purpose.

Comment: Create if it is possible a sample project where it is possible to reproduce your problem